# Angular 5 project is not detecting changes on file Change/Save

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I just created a project in angular 5 and it doesn't detected changes on file change/save not even reload the browser when I change anything on any file, and after change something on file I refresh browser manually it doesn't even detected changes but when i do `ng serve` again it detected all changes.

`ng -v` below

[image]

Comment: try `ng build --watch`

Comment: @RahulSingh it stuck on `chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 3.2 MB [initial] [rendered]`